# Use prototype javascript in dom element

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, prototypejs

Forgot my initial typo in original snippet here is exaly want I trying to do:

How can I use prototyped variable in Dom element event?

Suppose :

```js
function MyProto(){
  this.valeur = "toto";
}

MyProto.prototype = {
  func1: function() {
     var t = document.createTextNode("func1 called ");
    document.body.appendChild(t);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(br);        
    this.func2();
  },
  func2: function() {
     var t = document.createTextNode("func2 called");
     document.body.appendChild(t);
  }
};

var proto = new MyProto();
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click",proto.func1);
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Press here</button>
```

In this example, when I press button it throw me this.func2 is not a function. I must to mention that ultimately the Dom element will be generated by HtmlHelper from Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: I have updated my answer below to include your second problem's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First Problem

That's just a typo, you are calling `funct1` instead of `func1`

#### Second Problem (Update)

The problem is when you add the listener your way:
`.addEventListener("click",proto.func1)`

`this` will be the clicked element, not your `proto` instance, to solve this problem you can wrap it in another function clause, like the snippet below.

```js
function MyProto() {
  this.valeur = "toto";
}

MyProto.prototype = {
  func1: function() {
    var t = document.createTextNode("func1 called ");
    document.body.appendChild(t);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(br);
    this.func2();
  },
  func2: function() {
    var t = document.createTextNode("func2 called");
    document.body.appendChild(t);
  }
};

var proto = new MyProto();
document.getElementById("myButton2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  proto.func1()
});
```

```html
<button id="myButton1" onclick="proto.func1()">First Button</button>
<button id="myButton2">Second Button</button>
```

Comment: I already knew how to do that. I wondered how to call the func2 in the proto WITHOUT the wrapping of func1 in the event handler. See my updated answer

Comment: @mplungjan Then you could use [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and pass `proto`. Like this: `.addEventListener("click", proto.func1.bind(proto))`

Comment: Very a big thank you for both of you. You saved me from a severe headhache :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Answering the initial question:** Fixing the typo works with your inline event

**Answering SECOND question - how to use addEventListener and retain `this`:**

Safe solution - wrap call in a function in the event handler:

```js
function MyProto(){
  this.valeur = "toto";
}

MyProto.prototype = {
  func1: function() {
    var t = document.createTextNode("func1 called ");
    document.body.appendChild(t);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(br);   
    console.log(this)
    this.func2();
  },
  func2: function() {
     var t = document.createTextNode("func2 called");
     document.body.appendChild(t);
  }
};

var proto = new MyProto();
document.getElementById("myButton1")
  .addEventListener("click",() => proto.func1() )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 125px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myButton1">addEventListener now works</button>
<hr/>
```

Trials to find how to retain the prototype `this` when using addEventlListener **WITHOUT** wrapping in a function.

**NOTE** button 2 shows the code I wrote which is now used by OP for followup question

```js
function MyProto(){
  this.valeur = "toto";
}

MyProto.prototype = {
  func1: function() {
    var t = document.createTextNode("func1 called ");
    document.body.appendChild(t);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    document.body.appendChild(br);   
    console.log(this)
    this.func2();
  },
  func2: function() {
     var t = document.createTextNode("func2 called");
     document.body.appendChild(t);
  }
};

var proto = new MyProto();
document.getElementById("myButton2").addEventListener("click",proto.func1)
document.getElementById("myButton3").addEventListener("click", proto.func1.bind(proto))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 125px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="proto.func1()">Here <i>this</i> is the prototype</button>
<button type="button" id="myButton2">addEventListener has unexpected <i>this</i></button>
<button type="button" id="myButton3">addEventListener bound <i>this</i></button>
<hr/>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to include your second problem's solution